# Heroku backend Node.js and Netlify frontend react app has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cors, netlify

Heroku backend Node.js and Netlify frontend react app has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've seen a lot of posts on this, but I just can't seem to fix what's creating this error. Of course, I believe it has to do with CORS. But as you can see, I've added multiple versions of CORS middleware to allow this to work. Locally everything is fine. Production/live is where I get the issue:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://seb-youtube-api.herokuapp.com//videos?page=1&limit=50' from origin 'https://seb-youtube-api.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here is my backend server with Node.js and Express.js
They make a simple call to a youtube API.

```
      require('dotenv').config();
      const express = require('express');
      const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
      const app = express();
      const cors = require('cors')
      const chalk = require('chalk');
      const { google } = require('googleapis');
      const youtube = google.youtube('v3'); // initialize the Youtube API library 


      // Middleware 
      app.use(cors());
      app.use(bodyParser.json());

      /******************** GET REQUEST TO VIDEOS *********************/
      app.get('/videos', async (req, res) => {
        const results = await fetchYoutubePlaylist();
        res.json(results)
      })

      // /******************** POST REQUEST, USER SEARCH *********************/

      app.post('/videos', async (req, res) => {
        console.log('POST QUERY',req.body)
        const query = req.body
        res.body = await fetchYoutubeSearch(query)
        console.log("RES POST", res.body)
        res.json(res.body) 
      })


      app.use('*', cors(), (req, res) => {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Not Found' });
      });


      // CORS
      app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,multipart/form-data,Authorization');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE');
        if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
          return res.send(204);
        }
        next();
      });

      /******************** FIRST YOUTUBE API CALL *********************/
      const fetchYoutubePlaylist = async () => {
        try {
          const {data} = await youtube.playlistItems.list({
            key: process.env.YOUTUBE_API_TOKEN,
            part: ['snippet'],
            maxResults: 50,
            playlistId: "UUBh8XcZST_JTHt-IZDxT_pQ"
          })
          console.log(data)
          return data.items
        } catch(err) {
          console.log(chalk.red(err))
        }

      }


      /******************** SECOND YOUTUBE API CALL *********************/
      const fetchYoutubeSearch = async ({query}) => {
        console.log(query)
        try {
          const {data} = await youtube.search.list({
            key: process.env.YOUTUBE_API_TOKEN,
            part: ['snippet'],
            q: query,
            channelId: 'UCBh8XcZST_JTHt-IZDxT_pQ',
            order: 'date',
            type: 'video',
            maxResults: 50
          })
          console.log('YOUTUBE SEARCH', data)
          return data.items
        } catch(err) {
          console.log(chalk.red(err))
        }
      } 




      /******************** LIST TO PORT  *********************/

      const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
      app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listing on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the issue that your browser is blocking CORS? That happens to me with Heroku stuff sometimes. There are browser extensions to block/unblock CORS depending on the browser you're using

Comment: Good question. I just tried on a different browser, (safari). I typically use google chrome. Neither work.

Answer (score -1):

Stick only with `app.use(cors());` that alone should work fine. Instead double check your Config Vars (env vars) on heroku and/or netlify wherever you set such variables. Sometimes that CORS error can be misleading being actually a connection error more about your environment variables.